# Track any file changes using auditd

Tags: pci-dss, auditd

I try configure PCI REQ 10.5.5
"Use file integrity monitoring or change detection software on logs"

Use `auditd` for this,
rule `auditctl -w /tmp/testfile -p war` works perfectly.

But if I try to use stdout redirect on file like `echo "hi" >> /tmp/testfile`
Line is appended but in `audit.log` have no changes.

Is anybody knows how log all changes in file by using `auditd`?

Comment: What OS/distribution/version are you implementing this on?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 12.04.4

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this on Centos 6.3 and got the same result.  Reading the file tripped auditd but the append using echo did not.

Including x seems to work.  Change `-p war` to `-p warx` and see if that works for you on Ubuntu.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

auditd does catch the change to the file, but it is logged as bash making a syscall, unfortunately with no identifiable path back to the file that was changed.

As a workaround, for each rule to monitor a file, I include the file in the key name.  For example:

`-w /etc/login.txt -p wa -k login.txt-modified`

That way, log entries triggered with `echo > login.txt` will be easily found.  There is an open bug with Red Hat about this:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1204937

Answer (score 0):

I actually wouldn't use auditd alone for this. For my PCI and HIPAA-compliant systems, I used `auditd` to record changes on critical system files and functions, but leveraged either [AIDE](http://aide.sourceforge.net) or [Tripwire](http://www.tripwire.org) for actual file-integrity monitoring and reporting.

Comment: Yep, I'll try to use inotify with auditd.